# How to combine same labels into one row and sum all totals for each corporation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to either combine the hotels by corporation into sub groups, or simply have a table created with the total nights stayed by parent corporation.

[image: Worksheet screenshot]

Comment: I can't see any link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the whole table
2. Insert > Pivot Table > OK
3. Drag *Corporation* to ROWS, then drag *Nights* to VALUES. As default, you should get the sum of nights, grouped by corporation.

[image: Pivot table grouping]